# Call functionality in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<p id="phonenumber">Tap to call 0800 151 3325</p>
```

Please refer the above code snippet.This is my HTML tag in which I am displaying a number to let the user know to call on this.

I haven't used any javascript on this element to make a call but still in the UI when I tap on the number it is getting called.

I am unable to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Thats a feature of your mobile phone I guess, has nothing to do with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place this meta tag inside your head tag.

The "telephone-no" means that telephone numbers in the html should not appear as a link.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
```